# Remote (Ubuntu) server as http gateway to multiple socks5 proxy servers

Tags: proxy, squid, port-forwarding, gateway, socks

I have the following setup:

- Computer L (my Mac OS X machine).
- Linode R0 running Ubuntu 12.04.
- Linode R1 running Ubuntu 12.04.
- Linode R2 running Ubuntu 12.04.

R1 and R2 are turned into SOCKS5 proxy servers as follows:

```
user@R0: ssh -D 1081 R1
user@R0: ssh -D 1082 R2
```

Now, how would I go about having R0 to act as a simple HTTP/HTTPS proxy server and accept authenticated (a la Squid, can't get danted-server to work) incoming HTTP connections from my local computer which are randomly forwarded to R1 or R2?

Don't want to local port forward to R0 so please no `ssh -L` solutions.